# Why does MinGW and GCC give me different outputs for this simple program?

Tags: c++, gcc, runtime-error, mingw

In a freshman CSc college course with C++, we had a problem to convert a decimal number to a binary value.

My code for this is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int x, bin=0, i=0;
    cin>>x;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        bin+=(x%2)*pow(10,i++);
        x/=2;
    }
    cout<<bin;
    return 0;
}
```

When I built it on Kubuntu 15.10 using gcc 5.2.1 with no extra build flags, I get the expected output of `10100` for an input of `20`.

Yet, when I build it when MinGW packaged with CodeBlocks 13.12 on Windows 10, I get the output of `10098` for the same input of `20`.

This bizarre deviation from the right answer increases with the number of places for the final output in MinGW. What could be going wrong and why is the MinGW output give me the wrong answer?

Comment: I would suspect the pow function operates on floating point. Maybe try bin+=(x%2)*(int)round(pow(10,i++));

Comment: Floating point arithmetic isn't exact. (Perhaps your Linux build uses 80-bit floating point arithmetic, and the WIndows one uses 64 bits, leading to different precisions.) Don't use floating point arithmetic for an integer problem.